# Integrating $\int_0^1 \ln(1-t^{a}) dt . $

Tags: integration

I would like to know how to calculate this integral

$$
A= \int_0^1 \ln(1-t^{a}) dt  .
$$
I tried Taylor expansion for $\ln(1-t^{a})= -t^{a}$ , that gave me this :
$$
A=  \lim_{ x \rightarrow 0+} \int_0^1 -t^{a} dt =\dfrac{-1}{a+1} 
$$

is this result correct ?

Comment: What is $a$?  Also you should check what the proper Taylor expansion is and make sure it is valid.

Comment: a is a fixed parameter, a real number

Comment: Note that the Taylor _expansion_ does not simply have a single term.

Comment: @user2161721 : Check what happens when $a \le 0$. $a$ can't be any real number.

Answer (score 2):

For a>0,

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \ln(1-t^{a}) dt &= \sum_{n\ge 1}\int_0^1 -\frac{t^{na}}{n}\\
&= -\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n\,(na+1)}\\
&= -\mathrm{H}_{\frac{1}{a}}
\end{align}

The summation is called a Harmonic number. Some values are given in the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments

Comment: I agree. This is consistent with the relationship between Harmonic numbers and the digamma function.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to include digamma formula also, but why rewrite it here when wiki says it all!

Comment: can we tell about the nature of this integral using Riemann, its convergent right ?

Comment: @user2161721 : We can pick any test for covergence which may suit here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that $A=\frac{-1}{a+1}$  For real $a>0$ , in general, the result cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions.

[image]
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html